# Nested json argument in node child process bash script

Tags: node.js, bash

I am trying to use node to execute a bash command that takes a nested json object as an argument. I am finding that nested json does not work.

For example trying to convert this bash command. Notice `awscloudformation` is a nested object.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'

AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"project\",\
\"useProfile\":true,\
\"profileName\":\"testing\"\
}"
PROVIDERS="{\
\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG\
}"

amplify init \
--providers $PROVIDERS \
```

Here is the node script that does not work as expected. Providers seems to be ignored and is not overriding the defaults like the above bash script.

```
const arguments = [
  '--providers',
  `{"awscloudformation":{"configLevel":"project","useProfile":true,"profileName":"testing"}}`,
];
const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true };
require('child_process').spawn('amplify init', getArgs(), opts);
```

Would `exec` be better suited here? It seems I would need to include a variable similar to how `$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG` is being used in the bash script.

It is interesting to note that other arguments that are not nested seem to work fine. For example this amplify argument works fine:

```
  '--amplify',
  '{"projectName":"checking987","envName":"dev","defaultEditor":"code"}',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `shell: false` here :

```
const arguments = [
  '--providers',
  `{"awscloudformation":{"configLevel":"project","useProfile":true,"profileName":"testing"}}`,
];
const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', shell: false };
require('child_process').spawn("amplify", ["init", ...arguments], opts);
```

In shell mode, double quotes are removed.

Adapted shell mode version which works :

```
const arguments = [
  '--providers',
  `{\\"awscloudformation\\":{\\"configLevel\\":\\"project\\",\\"useProfile\\":true,\\"profileName\\":\\"testing\\"}}`,
];
const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true };
require('child_process').spawn("amplify init", arguments, opts);
```